# Showing two launcher icon for same application in certain android devices . Please give me a solution to rectify this issue

Tags: java, android, mobile, mobile-application

I have installed same application over the old one. Most of the devices working as expected, but some of them are showing two launcher icons and that two are pointing to same app. One of my client reporting this issue and I can't recreate it. How can I solve it. please help me anyone.Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you saying that there 2 instances of your app in the same device with 2 different app icons??

Comment: post your manifest code

Comment: Is it 100% in the launcher? You can add as many shortcuts to a home screen as you want in Android, could it be that they are seeing multiple icons on a home screen?

Comment: all device have working fine but some of the device, my client is using lg700
that device contain two launcher icon how..?

Comment: post your manifest file

Comment: there is one activity contain intent-filter..it was big manifest file so which part   you want

Comment: <application
        android:name=".PPPFlatRateApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" > <activity
  android:name=".Home"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
 <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
 </activity>

Comment: Please edit your question to include manifest. Also post complete manifest because that is the most likely place where your problem is. Posting pieces will not help to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you Manifest file that you added two activity as launcher category. like

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is the reason that you have two different launcher icon for same application.

thanks